# A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have been working on a Flutter app, and initially, it was running smoothly on both Android and iOS platforms. However, recently, I encountered an issue with the iOS version. I did a bunch of things to fix it, but I now face a new issue where the Android version of the app is not running.

The IDE log:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':share_plus:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 30s
```

Flutter doctor shows this issue

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
```

When i tried runing `flutter doctor --android-licenses`. It gives this

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/SdkManagerCli has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
Android sdkmanager tool was found, but failed to run (/Users/rashmi/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager): "exited code 1".
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
```

I tried updating SDK tools, but the problem persists.

[image]

Comment: @AnandhKrishnan Not yet

Comment: have you tried upgrading share_plus: ^7.2.2 library

Comment: @AnandhKrishnan yes but nothing has changed

Comment: if possible share me ur anydesk id, or try upgrading your java version, it should me minimum 17 for your project I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` commands after updating the SDK tools has fixed this issue

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/137022

flutter doctor --android-licenses fails with recent Android SDK tools